# remove parent (header) of button, and add textarea in its place

Tags: jquery

I have this html right now:

```
<h1><span class = 'highlight'><input type='image' class='removeall' src='remove.png'>
    <input type='image' class='edit' src='edit.png'>
    {$result['title']}</span></h1>

<form action = "addin.php" method="get">
<textarea name="add" id="add"></textarea>
You have <span id="charsLeft"></span> chars left
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

What I want to do in jquery is onclick of the .edit `<input>` type, `<h1></h1>` and its contents would be removed, and the later html (textarea) should fadein in its place. Anyone know a simple way to do this?

Comment: For a better page rank I would suggest you to use `h1` tags once-per-page and to leave it clean (with no `span` and specially NOT with `input` inside!) CSS is our friend, you can style your page in 1000 different (better) ways

Comment: I'd also suggest you to validate your markup! `</br>` is wrong. Use linebreaks `<br>` or `<br />` for xhtml

Comment: Praneet, what with the `.removeall` ? Should it be removed too? What is it's purpose?

Comment: ahh SO didn't add my complete entry (the big space being the evidence) but I want to remove <h1></h1> and its contents

Comment: Praneet, as the Q is a bit unclear... may you please see my answer and my demo and suggest changes? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').hide();
    $('.edit').click(function(){
        $('.edit').val('');
        $('#add').fadeIn();
    });
    $('.highlight').unwrap();
});
```

Comment: How would I then remove the <h1></h1> and its contents ...on the click

Comment: Hi Praneet hope you try this code and would be working fine, updated a minutes before

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VgRzf/)

```
$('.removeall, #editForm').hide();

$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('form#editForm').fadeToggle(800);
    $('.btn').toggle();
});
```